# How to convert units for all tags in a SVG using Inkscape Command Line or Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, svg, command-line, inkscape, unit-conversion

I use **mm** as my unit while creating SVG drawings in INKSCAPE and for a program I'm working on, I need units of all the shapes to be converted to **pts**

Is there any way to convert the units of every xml tag in the SVG from **mm** to **pt** most preferably using **Python3** else **Inkscape Command Line**

**(i.e.) Convert the below SVG**

```xml
<svg
   width="108mm"
   height="108mm"
   viewBox="0 0 108 108"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20)"
    @@ -38,46 +38,46 @@
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-52.715782,-77.867737)">
    <g
       id="g738">
      <circle
         style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0"
         id="path53"
         cx="106.71578"
         cy="131.86774"
         r="54" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="path179"
         cx="106.71578"
         cy="131.86774"
         r="17.5" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle261"
         cx="106.71578"
         cy="92.367737"
         r="8" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle263"
         cx="106.71578"
         cy="171.36774"
         r="8" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle722"
         cx="131.86774"
         cy="-146.21579"
         r="8"
         transform="rotate(90)" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle724"
         cx="131.86774"
         cy="-67.215782"
         r="8"
         transform="rotate(90)" />
    </g>
  </g>
```

**to**

```xml
<svg
   width="306.1422pt"
   height="306.1422pt"
   viewBox="0 0 306.1422 306.1422"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20)"
    @@ -38,46 +38,46 @@
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-149.4307914463,-220.72778068705)">
    <g
       id="g738">
      <circle
         style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0"
         id="path53"
         cx="302.501885777"
         cy="373.798889191"
         r="153.0711" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="path179"
         cx="302.501885777"
         cy="373.798889191"
         r="49.606375" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle261"
         cx="302.501885777"
         cy="261.83020568705"
         r="22.6772" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle263"
         cx="302.501885777"
         cy="485.76756419099996"
         r="22.6772" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle722"
         cx="373.798889191"
         cy="-414.47058912349996"
         r="22.6772"
         transform="rotate(90)" />
      <circle
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0"
         id="circle724"
         cx="373.798889191"
         cy="-190.5332164463"
         r="22.6772"
         transform="rotate(90)" />
    </g>
  </g>
```

> Note that in the given example (Consisting only of circles) the conversion took place at the following attributes
>
> width, height, viewBox, transform(), r, cx and cy
>
> A general solution that works on all shapes and path xml tags is required

> Edit :
> Note that no scaling is done here. (i.e.) 108mm = 306.1422pt and so on.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: I'm sure you can read an XML file in python, change the attributes and write out the modified file. All together though this is too broad. If you implement it and get stuck we can help though.

Comment: I already made a program that reads a SVG file, parse it and replace the units but it was only limited to circles. Performing the same for countless variety of shapes and paths a SVG has is too tedious and hence am looking for an alternative way. Here is the link for that program I made earlier. https://github.com/SayadPervez/efcnc_gui/blob/master/pyprogs/reform.py

Comment: You should add at least the parts of your code that you find unsatisfying and incomplete into the question itself. Stack Overflow really wants questions to be self-contained.

Comment: Am actually looking for an alternative approach. (i.e.) A way to read the SVG using cario module, set document type to "pt" and save the file (or) an INKSCAPE command to do the same. Making a parsing algorithm to replace every part of the file with appropriate unit is vile effort !